# Php convert null value inside array to blank (" ")

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am returning all shipping address saved by user but there are some values which are left blank and output comes as null in those. How can i convert NULL values to blank (" "). I have looked many solutions on internet but not able to get make it working.
API link:

```
https://androidapp.factory2homes.com/api/shippings/3
```

```
$address = DB::table('shippings')->where('user_id' , $user_id)->get();
  return $address;
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us your "many solutions", and tell us why they don't work? For now: make your `address` a true eloquent model, for example model `Shipping`. Return that model in a response, either by simply returning the model or by returning a model resource. Either way, internally laravel calls several functions to get the attribute values. You have the ability to access these attributes, turning null values into blanks. See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just map the return value like:

```
return $address = DB::table('shippings')
                    ->where('user_id' , $user_id)
                    ->get()
                    ->map(function ($item) {
                       $mapped = [];

                       foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                           $mapped[$key] = $value ?? ' ';
                       }
                       
                       return $mapped
                    });
```